# Download Speed is consistently at 16kbps

Tags: download

I'm using Comcast, and I'm using a Linsys WRT54G2 router. I'm testing a MegaUpload Premium download using jDownloader and it is just staying at 15 or 16kbps. There is clearly a problem there. How can I fix this?

My speed tests from speakeasy and speedtest.net are getting 5mbps - 7mbps download with 3.5mbps upload

Comment: You may want to test your connection speed at [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) to see whether your connection is at fault or MegaUpload simply applies bandwidth restriction.

Comment: Try connecting a computer directly to your modem, bypassing the router. This should help you isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the signal. My signal was at -19 dbmv. You can check this in your diagnostics throu the cable modem, 192.168.100.1. In this situation, you have to call Comcast and get them out here to fix it.

Comment: Since this seems to be related to your router (correct me if I am wrong), it would have matched my answer and the corresponding comments, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the port security and bandwidth options of your router?

Comment: and jDownloader settings

Comment: It's happening in Chrome too, so its not because of a the program. Also in Firefox.

Comment: Like I said, I suggest you to check your router settings.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is your Internet Connection type? Is it good? You should check line parameters if you have ADSL.

Second, Linksys WRT54G2 with stock firmware is impossible to bandwidth management. So please check another file sharing hosts, such as mediafire.com, etc.. to make sure about problem with Megaupload.

Third, check your firewall app or any shaping traffic app you may have in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue with Comcast by powering my router off for 30 seconds, powering the modem off for 30 seconds, then renewing the IP address (certain routers will let you renew your public IP on demand). This happens to me about once every 6-8 months, according to the the tier 3 tech(which I finally escalated to) The DNS cache needs to be refreshed, he had no permanent fix for me...